# Confused Between Task Queue and Cron Jobs

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have around 1000 entries in my datastore and this is likely to increase with time to around 10,000 entries. My task is to update each row's certain properties and save it back and this task has to be performed every 24 hours.

So, what should I use?

Comment: You can use [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/) to achieve this. Its open source library in java and can be used for scheduling task every 24 hours.

Comment: cron is exactly for this, with `every 24 hour` schedule option. but remember that in contrast to task queue cron jobs are not rescheduled after failure. so most reliable way is to start task queue from cron job

Comment: @IgorArtamonov there is a time limit for cron jobs which is 10mins. so will this task be completed within 10 mins. like if I have to update 50,000 entries will it be done within 10 mins ?

Comment: @Nayanjain You don't have to update all at the same time. If you use the datastore your can use a cursor query to walk through the data. Do a couple thousand at a time and reschedule a task with the cursor as parameter to handle the next batch. So basically you would use both task queue and cron jobs for this.

Comment: Another option is to kick off mapreduce from the cron job. For the scheduling part, cron job is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you create a cron job that runs every 24 hours.

Second, you need to decide what this cron job will do. The simplest option is to update all 1,000 records. You can retrieve and save all entities in large batches (i.e. 500 per call). If this is a simple update of values, it will take just a few seconds.

Since cron jobs are not retried if they fail, a better option is to create a task and add it to the queue. All updates will happen within that task.

NB: Make sure that if your task is retried, it won't mess the data. If this is not possible, you will have to use some kind of flag (i.e. timestamp of last update) to separate updated entities from those that still need updates.

As your data set grows, your cron job can start multiple tasks to update, for example, 1,000 records in each task.

Answer (score 1):

In the task queue the tasks have to be added to the queue manually though code. If you want to do this task automatically every x time, what you need is a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

You need both,

- Cron job to start your batch update job every 24 hours
- Task-queues to process you records.